# How to set image open-with via terminal?

Tags: xdg-open

I am running openbox and so do not have access to standard Ubuntu control panel, but must set everything from the terminal. When I download an image in chrome and click open, it launches xdg-open which then launches an arbitrary program (it resorts to Internet Explorer on wine if I uninstall those programs).

How do I control which program is loaded for an image of type .jpg (and others)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the command `nano ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (to set for your user only) or `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (to set for all users).
2. Find the mime type of the file you want to change (.jpg is `image/jpeg`). You can find the mime type with the command `file --mime-type -b filename`
3. Replace (or add) the line so it reads `image/jpeg=eog.desktop` (replacing `image/jpeg` with the type and `eog.desktop` with the .desktop which you want to use to launch the program.

Note: 
If you are using `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, you may need to create it see here: [Default Applications - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications#How_it_should_work)